# How do I interpret GeoIP.DAT?

Tags: geolocation, geo, maxmind

Maxmind offers a GeoIP.DAT file format like this (http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCountry/GeoIP.dat.gz)

```
0100 007e 0000 0200 003f 0000 0300 0021
0000 0400 0013 0000 0500 000c 0000 0600
0009 0000 0700 0008 0000 dd00 00e3 0000
1f01 00e1 ffff 0a00 000b 0000 5301 007c
0100 e1ff ff84 0100 0d00 0010 0000 0e00
000f 0000 8c01 00a8 0100 00ff ffe1 ffff
```

How do I interpret the binary information which is shown above? How di I correlate with what is shown in the spec http://maxmind.github.io/MaxMind-DB/

Comment: The spec is for the MMDB format, not the legacy DAT format. You can find the Country MMDB file at http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb.gz. Is there any particular reason why you are trying to read the binary as opposed to using one of the APIs? If you are trying to write your own API, the spec should be sufficient to do so.

Comment: I also need to read geoip.dat file from c#. Anyone?